# Use 3-8 MUX instead of Case statement

Tags: verilog, microprocessor, alu, processor

I've been thinking about implementing a very simple ALU, and came across this link [Verilog 8 Bit ALU](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/215980/verilog-8-bit-alu). This seems to be a very naive and abstract but intuitive implementation. I'm thinking about breaching the abstraction layers here, and take the implementation to the gate level. The first step in this IMO would be to use a 3-8 Multiplexer for selecting a particular ALU module instead of the Case statement. However, I'm unable to think of a way to do so in verilog. Can anyone please provide a code snippet that does this may be, or point me to the right direction.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you asking how to write code for a multiplexer?

Comment: Why do you think that a case statement in your verilog won't produce a multiplexer in the synthesized implementation?

Comment: I don't think that. In fact, I don't really know that. I haven't had much experience with verilog. When I was trying to design schematics for the ALU, the obvious choice was to use a Multiplexer for decoding opcodes, and I can't see it being explicitly replicated in the code.

Comment: @BilalWasim, the whole point of using HDL is to *infer* the logic rather than explicitly define it. Once you are used to the paradigm, it lets you think on a higher level and keep a bigger design in your head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most usual way to write a multiplexer in Verilog is with a case statement:

```
reg mux_out;
always @ (*)
begin : 
    case(sel ) 
        1'b0 : mux_out = din_0;
        1'b1 : mux_out = din_1;
    endcase 
end
```

For a 2:1 mux like this, it might be just as clear to write it using the ternary operator:

```
wire mux_out;
assign mux_out = sel ? din_1 : din_0;
```

But for larger muxes, the case statement is easier to read.

You could of course build one up from gates, but there's no reason to expect this to produce any different result from synthesis. You'd just build it up from the SOP representation. For a 2-1 mux:

```
wire mux_out;
assign mux_out = ~sel & din_0 | sel & din_1;
```

I wouldn't recommend to do this, though, because it makes your design harder to understand. Generally you should prefer to code at the highest level of abstraction possible, in order to make your code clearer to whoever has to debug it.

Comment: Does the current state of compiler/floorplanning tools do a good job of mapping abstract designs to specific FPGA cell functional units? My experience (and it is not a lot) has been that I've had to manually floorplan way more than I thought I needed to in order to minimize usage. And/or learn idiomatic ways of writing that the compiler tools would "understand" better.

Comment: @jonk, I have only ever hand-placed things to get very high speeds, for example feeding a DDR IO pin running at 800 MHz (IIRC) in Virtex-E. You may have incorrect expectations of the tool It is not trying to achieve the most dense placement. It is trying to minimize compile time while meeting all constraints. If constraints are met, then denser placement is of no value to the user...

Comment: For example, the tool will deliberately not use two LUTs in the same cell if it doesn't have to, because that creates routing congestion which will increase the compile time needed to find a routing solution that meets timing.

Comment: Most FPGA designers I've worked with try to choose a device with at least 2x the resources they expect to need, because once resource usage exceeds 60-70% or so, compile times go through the roof.

Comment: Appreciated. In my case I was working with a small 4000 series FPGA and designing a small CPU, eventually using almost ALL of the resources. I first designed it by looking at the cells and then carefully crafting my design for that. Then, and only then, did I try to learn VHDL to code it. The Xilinx floorplanner didn't find the optimizations I did and would have required something a LOT bigger. I think more than 4 or 5 times larger, actually. Different expectations, as you say. Thanks very much for the good point.

Comment: @jonk, synthesis has come a long way since the 4000 series was current, but still I wouldn't try to pack a device more than 80%. I do know of cases where careful placement is used to achieve better than typical consistency of timing, for example to do time-of-flight measurements for io signals returning to probe the signal integrity on a line.

Comment: I was just amazed at how poorly it matched up my VHDL syntax with existing function units I was mentally targeting when I wrote it out. I thought it would link the two up well. Instead, I'd see it do almost crazy/dumb things and use almost entirely inappropriate resources -- or it would split something into two different cells, using up routing paths across the entire device for gosh sake, when a single cell had ALL that was required and there was no need to split things up like that. I'm glad it is a lot better now. I need to get back into this. Perhaps a Digilent board is ahead of me.

Comment: @jonk, Xilinx has a document called "Synthesis Guide" that gives exact syntax recommended to produce specific features, like muxes, state machines, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look that up, tonight. And consider getting an FPGA board to play with. Nothing serious. Just pleasure.